# c++ valgrind memory leak even if memory is apparently freed

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have a class A with a double pointer member

```
double * _E;
```

for which memory is allocated in the constructor of the class as

```
_E(new double)
```

now the class has to deal with two scenarios. One in which it works by itself, in which case _E is deleted in the destructor. Or another case in which it needs to cooperate with another class B on this same member.

In the latter case, I want to reset the location of _E to another address. For this purpose I have written a member function A::wrap_E

```
void A::wrap_E(double &E){
      double Eval = *_E;
      delete _E;
      _E = &E; //relocate address
      *_E = Eval;
      _wrap_E = true;
  }
```

where I reset the address of _E to that of E passed by reference to the function (E belongs to B but is not a pointer, that's why I copy its address). So that the two classes can operate in turns on the same address (they do different things) and they are aware of the changes without passing E around. 
_wrap_E=true is a flag that I use to tell the destructor of A whether it should delete _E any longer: if _E wraps another E then it should not be delete by the destructor because memory has already been deallocated.

The code runs fine but Valgrind complains about a memory leak

```
==5014==  16 bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 48 of 1,413
==5014==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5014==    by 0x414661F: A::A(BasePotential*, Array<double>, double, double, Array<double>&, Array<double>&, Array<double>&) (A.h:119)
```

where line 119 of A.h is the line of the constructor where I call new: _E(new double).

Any suggestion on how I could fix this? I considered using shared_ptr but this introduces a problem when _E gets reset to &E because the shared_ptr takes ownership and it tries to delete something that belongs to B, and B is not aware of this change in ownership.

Comment: Learn about the rule of three (or of five). Other than that, without a complete testcase that we can take, compile and run and see for ourselves, this is just guesswork.

Comment: Why not just have the `shared_ptr` in both classes and drop this `wrap` stuff?

Comment: A side note: You should probably check `_wrap_E` in `wrap_E` before deleting `_E` to avoid double delete if you call `wrap_E` twice on an object. Secondly, this does seem like a proper use case for a `shared_ptr`. You are supposed to use shared_ptr for all owners of the object and that includes `B`. That way `B` *is* "aware of the ownership".

Comment: We need an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), or at the bare minimum, the definition of constructors, assignment operators and destructors of `A`, as well as any code which modifies `_E`.

Comment: Taking ownership of a value that you passed in by reference, is an extremely bad design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this problem arises from your use of `new`, the simplest solution would be to... well... not.

Instead of allocating the memory for the double on the heap, you can use an [automatic variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) so that you don't have to worry about `delete`ing it at some later point. For example:

```
class Foo
{
    double* _E;
    double _defaultE;

public:
    Foo()
        : _defaultE(0.0)
        , _E(&_defaultE) // Automatic variable, so no "new" or "delete"
    {
    }

    Foo(double* E)
        : _E(E)
    {
    }
}
```

If you do this, then you no longer have to deal with 2 scenarios; you've effectively funneled them into the same design.